# Parallax and Google Page Speed module conflict, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, google-pagespeed

we have recently installed Google Page Speed module on Magento with these filters enabled:

```
ah  Add Head
cw  Collapse Whitespace
cc  Combine Css
jc  Combine Javascript
gp  Convert Gif to Png
jp  Convert Jpeg to Progressive
jw  Convert Jpeg To Webp
mc  Convert Meta Tags
pj  Convert Png to Jpeg
ws  When converting images to WebP, prefer lossless conversions
db  Debug
dj  Defer Javascript
ec  Cache Extend Css
ei  Cache Extend Images
es  Cache Extend Scripts
fc  Fallback Rewrite Css 
if  Flatten CSS Imports
hw  Flushes html
ci  Inline Css
ii  Inline Images
il  Inline @import to Link
ji  Inline Javascript
js  Jpeg Subsampling
ll  Lazyload Images
rj  Recompress Jpeg
rp  Recompress Png
rw  Recompress Webp
rc  Remove Comments
ri  Resize Images
rx  Responsive Images
cf  Rewrite Css
rd  Rewrite Domains
jm  Rewrite External Javascript
jj  Rewrite Inline Javascript
cu  Rewrite Style Attributes With Url
cp  Strip Image Color Profiles
md  Strip Image Meta Data
```

We have parallax effect on two sections of the home page, top one (the first block you see when you visit site) and one right before footer.
The issue is that some times bottom one doesn't work as it should, it drags footer section inside parallax.

When we try with ?PageSpeedFilters=-defer_javascript it always works as expected. Note that I have added parallax library to load right after jquery, and that I called parallax on window.load so it should initialise when all scripts are there, but that didn't help. Has anybody encountered issue like this, or anyone has a solution for this?

P.S. Adding no-defer tag doesn't help as this library is jQuery dependant.

Thanks!